# $||f_{n}||_{0}=\sup|xf_{n}(x)|$, $f_{n}\in{C[0,1]}$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $f_{n}\in{C[0,1]}$

$||f_{n}||_{0}=\sup|xf_{n}(x)|$, where $x\in{[0,1]}$.

$||f_{n}||_{1}=\int_{0}^{1} |f_{n}(x)| dx$.

I want to find an example, such that,

$||f_{n}||_{0}\rightarrow{0}$  and $||f_{n}||_{1}\nrightarrow{0}$

Anyone has some ideas?

Comment: Did you want to write $\|f_n\|_0 = \sup |xf_n(x)|$? (same for $\|\cdot\|_1$)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I made a typo. But fix now.

Comment: @Arthur You are correct. I delete the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following sequence
$$ f_n(x) = \frac{c_n}{x+1/n}\in C^0([0,1]), $$
Where $c_n = \frac{1}{\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x+1/n}dx}$.
Then, $\int_0^1 f_n(x)=1$. We see that
$$ x+1/n \geq x+1/(n+1) \quad \iff \quad \frac{1}{x+1/n} \leq \frac{1}{x+1/(n+1)}, $$
whic implies that $\frac{1}{x+1/n}$ is an increasing sequence that converges pointwisely almost everywhere to $\frac{1}{x}$.
By monotone convergence theorem (Beppo-Levi)
$$ \lim_n \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x+1/n}dx = \int_0^1 \lim_n \frac{1}{x+1/n}dx = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}dx = \infty. $$
This shows that $c_n \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.
But then
$$ \sup_{x\in[0,1]} |xf_n(x)| = c_n \sup_{x\in[0,1]} \frac{x}{x+1/n} \leq c_n \cdot 1 = c_n \to 0.
$$

Comment: Wait, the exponentiation is kinda useless, let me edit

Comment: Thannk you!!  It is really not easy to think about such sequence function.

Comment: I edited, not it's very straightforward! I just picked $1/x$ and moved it a little to make it continuous. The trick was to use monotone convergence, but I took a while to figure it out

Comment: you can upvote it if you liked it!

Comment: Sorry, this is a new account. My vote will not be displayed.

Comment: Ok,no problem:)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: as an element of $C(0,1]$, we have $\|\frac1{nx}\|_0=\frac1n$ and $\|\frac1{nx}\|_1=\infty$. With some minor manipulation (change what the function looks like on $[0,\epsilon)$ for some small $\epsilon>0$) you can make it into an example that would work for you.

Comment: It's not continuous in 0.

Comment: @TommasoSeneci It's not even defined at $0$. I'm not saying that it's a final solution. I'm saying that this function sequence has the property we're after (converging to $0$ in one norm and not the other), and that it can be manipulated into a sequence in $C[0,1]$, without ruining the convergence properties. That's why I said "Hint" at the start.

Comment: Indeed, I already had this idea and tried several times. But I still failed to come up with the right function. Could you give more hint to me?

Comment: @XiongWenKE If you let $f_n(x)$ be constantly equal to $\frac 1{n\epsilon}$ from $x=0$ to $x=\epsilon$, and equal to $\frac1{nx}$ for $x>\epsilon$, then $\|f_n\|_0=\frac1n$. You can pick $\epsilon=\epsilon_n$ small enough that $\|f_n\|_1=1$, say (this must be proven, of course). And there you have your example.

Comment: The fact is that the shifting arguments would no lead anywhere. I tried to prove it by translating and changing rate of $\frac{1}{x}$ at the same time. Try to check it.

Comment: @TommasoSeneci I never said anything about shifting. The example I outlined in my previous comment has $f_n(x)=\frac1{nx}$ for most values of $x$, and not translated to $\frac1{x+a}$ or something. It's just that in order to handle the singularity at $x=0$, we make the function constant for very small $x$-values.

Comment: I see that you mean

Comment: @Arthur. Thank you. I got your idea.  I think if we set $\epsilon_{n}$=$e^{-n}$, the result will follow.

Comment: @XiongWenKE I haven't actually checked the exact value you would need, but that seems reasonable.

Comment: At the end a simple translation argument turned out to be enough, check it out